# Is it possible to change content in my PHP file from WordPress dashboard

Tags: php

Is it possible to change content in a "p" tag or "img" tag in my custom php template file, without going into code editor of the php file.

For example:
If I give the website over to the client, they may not have the skillset to updated the php file, but it will be easier for them to update the content in Wordpress Dashboard.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can put that text in a post meta if it's per page or an option if it's global to the site and then set up something on the dashboard to edit it. (I think this is easy to do with [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) but it's been a while since I used it, and plenty of other options are available, including writing the admin page for this yourself.)

Comment: Is it just a custom template or a full on custom theme you built, because you could add stuff like this as options for the client to manage.

Comment: @rup Thank you so much, I'll have a look into this :)

Comment: @TonyDjukic It's an Elementor theme, but I had to build a custom wordpress blog system

Comment: So did you build it as a custom plugin?  And why would you need a custom WordPress Blog System for WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Look into [Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/), or use the excellent [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) as [Rup mentioned](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/388115/is-it-possible-to-change-content-in-my-php-file-from-wordpress-dashboard#comment563129_388115)